# Keeping a counter inside a reduce function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a reduce function that assigns an incrementing integer to each new unique value in an array and builds a dictionary mapping the unique element to the incrementing index.

My desired function consumes an array like this:

```
[3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2]
```

and outputs a map that looks like this:

The function looks like this:

```
{3: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 5: 3}
```

One potential solution is to use reduce, but it requires keeping the counter outside of the function:

```
var i = 0
var func = [3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2].reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (!(a in b) { 
    b[a] = i
    i++
  }
  return b
},{})
```

Is there a way to write this function but somehow keep the counter inside the function's scope? Obviously I could wrap everything in a function, but is there a way to do this with just reduce?

Comment: @RobertRozas: That wouldn't work. `i` would always be 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a closure will help keeping your code clean:

```
fun=function(){
 var i=0;
 return function(b, a) {
  if (!(a in b)) { 
    b[a] = i
    i++
  }
  return b;
};
}();

var func = [3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2].reduce(fun,{})
```

So you have `fun` while reducing.

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.reduce takes 4 arguments.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) You might consider using them, since one of them is the index value. And thus the need for a counter is not necessary.

```
var func = [3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2].reduce(function(prev, curr, idx, arr) {
    if(!(prev in curr)) curr[prev] = (prev.length > 0) ? prev.length - 1 : 0;
    return curr;
});
```

Comment: But he's not strictly looking for index; he actually wants a *counter* (see how the example code doesn't increment `i` on every call, only when encountering a unique value).

Comment: I realized that index may not be the value you would need, but since the original array is passed in as the 4th argument, you can use that to grab the first index of the value who's position you're looking for instead of using an incremental variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can always throw `i` into the object itself:

```
[3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2].reduce(function(a,b) {
   if(a[b]===undefined) a[b] = a.i++; return a},{i:0})

// {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0, 5: 3, i: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but it's probably more awkward than just using a scoping function. Basically, you just make your state value a composite of the actual result you want and the additional state, and then you extract the result when you're done reducing.

```
var func = [3,1,1,2,3,1,5,1,2].reduce(function(memo, val) {
  if (!(val in memo[0])) { 
    memo[0][val] = memo[1]
    memo[1]++
  }
  return memo
}, [{}, 0])[0]
```